# how to create Mail Chimp style charts and graphs

Tags: php, jquery, css, charts

Take a look at this blog post mail chimp released a few months back:

http://blog.mailchimp.com/chimp-charts-are-here/

The ones you see there are pretty amazing looking, and they function great.  It uses Flash.
I'd love to know what they are using to make that happen, is anyone aware?

**Even better,** they also have other amazing looking charts that are NOT flash... take a look at this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/UGmlj.png]

This is the chart type that I am far more interested in.  The graphs flow up when the page loads (assuming jQuery) - and bounce into place.  Then, you can click them for links to more information.
Does anyone know if this is created fram scratch by them, or if there is a similar package that's available out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are literally hundreds and hundreds of premade chart libraries for JS (as well as Flash). Do a simple google search and you are bound to find what you are looking for. Otherwise most of it can be easily replicated by hand with jQuery (if you want them to be dynamic).

However, if you want to do curvy charts yourself with JavaScript then it's either HTML5 Canvas, http://raphaeljs.com/ or similar "technologies".

Random search hits on google:
http://www.highcharts.com/
http://g.raphaeljs.com/
http://javascript.open-libraries.com/utilities/chart/20-best-javascript-charting-and-plotting-libraries/
http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/free-javascript-charts-library-js-charts/